# Generating a monthly "Post Count" from Facebook API

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to figure out how I can query the FB Graph API (or FQL API) to be able to get number of posts (or status-updates) for a given period of time. I am able to generate an access token using

```
$access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
```

So that would lead me to believe that the PHP SDK is installed correctly and working. When I try to use the access token in a fql query it fails giving an error message of: A user access token is required to request this resource. The query I'm trying is just to return the current status_id. I tried using uid=me() as well as using an actual user id (testing id from the API). Here is the query url:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT+status_id+FROM+status+WHERE+uid=me()&access_token=
```

I'm not sure where I'm going off track with this, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you for looking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This is your app id and secret, please do not ever post this to public, anyone will have full control of your application. Reset your token immediately**

The PHP SDK defaults to the application access token (**which should never be posted in public**). You need to have the user login with `getLoginUrl()` an example is given at

https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk/blob/master/examples/example.php